# Which SAS output should be used to determine model adequacy for logistic regression

Tags: regression, self-study, logistic, sas, logit

I have the following data:

```
  x   y
  400 0
  220 1
  490 0
  210 1
  500 0
  270 0
  200 1
  470 0
  480 0
  310 1
  240 1
  490 0
  420 0
  330 1
  280 1
  210 1
  300 1
  470 1
  230 0
  430 0
  460 0
  220 1
  250 1
  200 1
  390 0
```

I'm tasked with fitting a logistic regression model with a logit link to the data and to determine if the model deviance indicates that the model is adequate. However, SAS gives two conflicting outputs. I think I should use the bottom output below with the likelihood ratio, which indicates that the model is useful in explaining $y$.

The reason I think that is because in the past, in R, I would do something like this to determine the model adequacy:

```
model <- glm (y ~ x, data = data, family = binomial)
summary(model)
1 - pchisq(34.617 - 20.364, 1)
```

which gives the same test statistic and p-value as the bottom picture.

The deviance in the top picture would indicate that the model is inadequate. Where does the deviance in the top picture comes from? What does it tell us?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is tests for goodness of fit. Their null hypotheses are the same: the difference between model predicted values and observed values are due to random variation, so the model is acceptable. When p-value is large (like in your case), it indicate there is no reason to reject the null hypothesis that model is good.

The second part are 3 tests to test the same null hypothesis: That all betas are zero (or all of the factors (covariates) in the model have no effect on the response variable). Small p-value (like in your case) indicates that that the chance of null hypothesis to be true is very low, so we have enough evidence to say that at least some of the factors in the model have effect on the response variable.

Comment: Based on the context of the question, any thoughts on which one I should use?

Comment: "to determine if the model deviance indicates that the model is adequate" for this question, use the first table, the model is good.